# how to increment the number in shared file using 3 processes' signal

Tags: c

Guys I've been working on this project for 3 days and it's still hard for me to understand what's wrong I have to make file with '0' in it([argv[2]). Each process increase it by 1 and wake next process up and go to sleep. (p1->p2->p3->p1 ,,, until it reaches argv[1]). Currently  I don't know why it firstly sends 2 signals without going into while loop.(initial0, 2xxxx, 2xxxx, 02xxxx,02xxxx ,,,,) and it doesn't increase one by one. should i use sigprocmask?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define buf 10
void sig_usr (int signo)
{
/*      sigset_t sigset;
        sigemptyset(&sigset);
        sigaddset(&sigset, SIGUSR1);
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&sigset, NULL);

        */printf("%d\n",getpid());
//      longjmp(jumpbuffer,1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{       int fd;
        int count = 0;
        char buff[buf];
        struct sigaction usrsig;
        usrsig.sa_handler =sig_usr;
        sigemptyset(&usrsig.sa_mask);
        usrsig.sa_flags=0;
        sigaction(SIGUSR1,&usrsig,0);
     if(!(argv[1]>0))
                printf("insert positive integer");
        fd = open(argv[2],O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC);
        pwrite(fd,"0",3,0);
        read(fd,buff,10);
        printf("initial%s\n",buff);

//      jmp_buf jumpbuffer;
        pid_t next,ppid,granmaduh;
        granmaduh = getpid();
        if ((next = fork()) <0 )
        { 
                        fprintf(stderr, "fork() error");
                        exit(1);
         }
        else if (next == 0  )
        {

  next = fork();
                if (next >0)
                {
                        sleep(6);
                }
                else 
                {
                        next = granmaduh;       
                        sleep(10);
                }
        }
        //setjmp(jumpbuffer);
        while(1)
        {
                //write(fd,buff[0],sizeof(buf));
                sleep(1);
  kill(next, SIGUSR1);
                printf("%s",buff);
                pause();
                sleep(1);

        }
//      while(1)
//      {}


        }
```

Comment: Another 'p1->p2->p3->p1' homework:(   Three named semaphores, (again).

Comment: I didnt learn named semaphore  i looked it up but  idk how to use it